# Converging or diverging series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

I have the following series: a) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n}\cdot\cos^2(n)}{n^2-2}$ and b) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)!(n+2)!}{n^{2n}}$

I have concluded that for a the ratio and root test are both inconclusive, and I understand I need to use the comparison test here as I have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ which seems to converges, but from here I am either on the wrong track or completely lost. Where can I go from here or what have I done wrong (if anything).

For b) the solution in the book states that by the ratio test, the solution converges. I know that this is true when $L<1$. To prove this would I just simply throw in values of $<1$ and show that $a_n < b_n$ ?

Where $\displaystyle a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)!(n+2)!}{n^{2n}}$  and $\displaystyle b_n = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2n}}$.

Any help for either case would be greatly appreciated. I have come to a cross roads and cant seem to move on.

Comment: One quick trick for (a) is to note if $a_{n}=\sqrt{n}\cos^{2}(n)/(n^{2}-2)$, then $0\leq a_{n}\leq \sqrt{n}/(n^{2}-2)$, since $0\leq\cos^{2}(n)\leq1$.

Answer (score 2):

For (a),

$$
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}\cos^{2}\left(n\right)}{n^{2}-2}\leq\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{2}-n^{2}/2}=2\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}<\infty
$$

For (b), let 
$$
a_{n}=\frac{\left(n+1\right)!\left(n+2\right)!}{n^{2n}}
$$
then
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{\left(n+2\right)!\left(n+3\right)!}{\left(n+1\right)^{2\left(n+1\right)}}\cdot\frac{n^{2n}}{\left(n+1\right)!\left(n+2\right)!}=\cdots
$$